# How to use "ICachedServiceProvider" to inject "Typed HttpClient" correctly?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, httpclient, abp

How to use "ICachedServiceProvider" to inject "Typed HttpClient" correctly?

I use `Typed HttpClient` and try to use `ICachedServiceProvider`, but I got an error.

```
var httpClient = _cachedServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
```

Error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> An invalid request URI was provided. Either the request URI must be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PrepareRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage request)

But it work fine when I use `Constructor Injection` for `Typed HttpClient`

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

public TestService(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient;
}
```

P.S. `ConfigureServices`:

```
private void ConfigureHttpClient(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
    var options = context.Services.ExecutePreConfiguredActions<TestOptions>();
    context.Services.AddHttpClient<ITestService, TestService>(httpClient =>
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = options.BaseAddress;
    });
}
```

So, how to use "ICachedServiceProvider" to inject "Typed HttpClient" correctly?

Edit:

I can use `IHttpClientFactory` to get named `HttpClient`, and it work now.

```
var httpClientFactory = _cachedServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(ITestService));
// ...
var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("oauth/token", testRequest);
```

Comment: Read up on `IHttpClientFactory`. It doesn't answer your question, but it may answer your need

Comment: I think you misunderstood typed clients vs named clients. I posted a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Typed clients vs named clients

First, an important clarification: in the question, `TestService` is the [typed client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#typed-clients).

- Typed clients are not `HttpClient` instances.

  > A typed client accepts an `HttpClient` parameter in its constructor[.]
- Named clients are `HttpClient` instances.

Next, a clarification about what the method calls do:

- [`AddHttpClient<ITestService, TestService>(httpClient => {...})`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions-addhttpclient-2(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-func((system-net-http-httpclient-1)))) configures a binding between the typed client `TestService` and a named client.
- `_cachedServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>()` returns a scope-cached `HttpClient`, not a typed client (neither `ITestService` nor `TestService` is passed) nor a named client (name is not passed). That's why it's not configured.
- [`httpClientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(ITestService))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.ihttpclientfactory.createclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) creates a named client, not the typed client (i.e. `TestService`).

Then, by definition, a typed client constructor-injects a named client.

`HttpService` is practically a lightweight wrapper around longer-lived HTTP connections. There should be no need to scope-cache it.

## How to use ICachedServiceProvider to inject typed clients correctly

Simply:

```cs
var testService = _cachedServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestService>();
```

You should constructor-inject `HttpClient` in `TestService`.

## About cached service providers and lifetimes

If you use `ICachedServiceProvider` to inject `IHttpClientFactory` (Singleton), you will actually get Singleton `IHttpClientFactory`. `CachedServiceProvider` just caches the instance for the scope, it does not (nor should it) change the lifecycle of the registered type.